# How to add comments in Eclipse with Django template plugin?

Tags: python, django

I am using Eclipse and I know that there are ways where I can multi select the lines and add the comments using some shortcut.

I have used Eclipse for Symfony Twig template and I used `ctrl+shift + /` and it commented all the lines.

But I am not able to find how to comment lines in Django template like:

```
{#  #}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one way to comment multiple lines in django templates that i am aware of is using {% comment %}....the content goes here....{% endcomment %}...and then the usual ctrl+shift+/ in eclipse will add the traditional html comments  in django templates..i hope this helps..